# JSON data types - numbers are converting to strings when it gets to the server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am loading a `CSV` file, parsing it into a `JSON` object, then I am converting those strings into numbers. They show as numbers in the browser console, then using AJAX I am sending the data to the server. When I console.log the data everything is strings? I though `JSON` could accept a variety of data types, so why is it going down the line as strings?

Here is the code.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
            var files = input.files[i];

                Papa.parse(files, {
                    header:false,
                    dynamictyping:true,
                    complete: function(results){
                        var input = results.data;

                        if(input[0][0] === 'Symbol' || input[0][0] === 'symbol'){
                            input.shift();
                        }
                        input.forEach(function(input){
                            jsonData.theData = theData;

                            var singleEntry = {
                                "symbol"    : input[0],
                                "date"      : input[1],
                                "open"      : Number(input[2]),
                                "high"      : Number(input[3]),
                                "low"       : Number(input[4]),
                                "close"     : Number(input[5]),
                                "volume"    : Number(input[6])
                                };


                            // Here we will try to do the daily computations of what is needed for data 
                            // such as percentage closed in the day and what not. 

                                var open = singleEntry.open;
                                var high = singleEntry.high;
                                var low = singleEntry.low;
                                var close = singleEntry.close;
                                /*                              
                                console.log(open);
                                console.log(high);
                                console.log(low);
                                console.log(close); */

                                //Get the Math variables for close percentage
                                var spread = high - low;
                                var closeDiff = close - low;
                                var answer = closeDiff / spread;

                                console.log(answer);
                                //Adding day closes to object
                                if (singleEntry.volume === 0){
                                    singleEntry["supportDay"] = false;

                                } else {

                                    if(answer <= .3999){

                                            singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
                                            singleEntry["supportDay"] = false;
                                            console.log("answer <= .39999");

                                    } else if (answer > .95) {

                                            singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
                                            singleEntry["supportDay"] = true;
                                            singleEntry["peakClose"] = true;
                                            console.log("answer > .95");

                                    } else {

                                            singleEntry["percentClose"] = answer;
                                            singleEntry["supportDay"] = true;                                   

                                    }
                                }

                                jsonData.theData.push(singleEntry);
                                console.log(singleEntry.supportDay);

                            return jsonData;
                            }); // End forEach loop

                        document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonData.theData[0]);

                        } // End Callback Complete      
                }); // End PapaParse
         } // End for loop
 });
```

So as you can see I can work with the objects and here is the console.log output on the browser, all that code is in the browser.

[image]

Now here is the console.log to the server:

[image]

This data gets imported straight into the database there is no working with the data in Node. In my database it imports as strings as well.

Thoughts? What am I missing?

Comment: JSON is always a string representation - it has to be parsed to create an object for use within JavaScript (or other languages) and once that happens JavaScript (or the other languages) treat the resulting object the same as any other object.

Comment: JSON is an object representation serialized as a String. I suspect you just need to call `JSON.parse` on the receiving end to deserialize the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JSON, you're inputs can be of various data types.However, it gets serialized as one big string and sent down the wire to your server as such. On the server side, the string needs to be parsed into an object again. That step will vary depending on what sort of language your server operates in.